# Start download automatically when files are copied completely

Tags: windows, ftp, file-management, file-transfer

I am trying to create a utility which can initiate download when files are copied on a FTP folder. I get these files from my another team. They copy new files during their day time and I start downloading these files next day. Due to slow network it takes a lot of time to download these files.

Is it possible to create a listener service which always listens to a particular network folder and downloads latest files from there?

Comment: What you describe is possible but would require programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

If:

- You want to try some "alpha" release software, and
- Assuming your firewall allows Torrent protocol, and
- You don't mind that this is not FTP-based

you can use [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html). What BT Sync does is your team can create a "share" folder, and you have the "secret key" for that shared folder. What BT Sync will do (after you set up your end with the secret key generated by your other team mate), BT Sync will check on the remote host, and download and sync the files across.

So what your teammate need to do:

- Install BT Sync
- Create a Shared Folder - which BT Sync will generate a secret key
- Share the secret key to you

What you need to do:

- Install BT Sync
- Create a "Sync" folder using the secret key that your team mate created and shared to you
- Wait until all your files are sync-ed across.
- Get to work :)

Note: These are "Sync" so any files deleted/modified on each end will get synced across. They do have a "read only" mode so it only sync one way, but you just need to go through the BT Sync help file for it.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem I prefer to use [Pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).  As stated in [their wiki page](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki),

> Pyinotify is a Python module for monitoring filesystem changes. Pyinotify relies on a Linux Kernel feature (merged in kernel 2.6.13) called "inotify".  "inotify" is an event-driven notifier; its notifications are exported from kernel space to user space through three system calls. Pyinotify binds these system calls and provides an implementation on top of them offering a generic and abstract way to manipulate those functionalities.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  FYI, we prefer answers that have a bit more substance to them, as I have illustrated.

Comment: ok i will respect this next time. btw there is also a port of pynotify for windows https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog